# Naming conventions for Memory Mapped files in windows

Tags: windows, memory-mapped-files

I have searched for an answer to this, but unfortunately I have had little luck in finding any information on it!

In essence: What is the set of valid names for a memory mapped file in windows?

- How long can they be?
- What are legal characters, e.g. are forward slashes, hyphens, punctuation, etc. legal?
- Are there limitations on character ordering, e.g. an mmf name cannot start with an underscore?

EDIT: I realize that the answer to this question might be "They are exactly the same as normal file naming conventions in Windows." However it is important that this be clarified.

Comment: Are you expecting that to be different from the set of validations performed on every other kind of file?

Comment: I have no expectation on this front. I would absolutely believe that it might be more or less restrictive than standard file names.

Comment: Sometimes a file is just a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew` corresponds to `CreateFileMapping`. The [documentation for `CreateFileMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says

> The name can have a "Global\" or "Local\" prefix to explicitly create
>   the object in the global or session namespace. The remainder of the
>   name can contain any character except the backslash character (\).
>   Creating a file mapping object in the global namespace from a session
>   other than session zero requires the SeCreateGlobalPrivilege
>   privilege. For more information, see Kernel Object Namespaces.

In other words, you can use any string you like as long as it doesn't contain a backslash.

Comment: So it turns out it is different than standard files - which have name restrictions on additional characters, such as the forward slash.

Comment: @ColinB: that depends; are you talking about the name of the underlying file, or the name of the file mapping object?  Raymond's answer addresses the latter.

Comment: @HarryJohnston In a comment to the deleted answer, you can see the ColinB was asking about `MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew`, which creates a file mapping not backed by a file. The name here is the name of the file mapping.

Comment: Ah, that explains it.  (I can't see the answer you're referring to; deleted answers are presumably only visible to the poster and those who commented on it.)  @ColinB: in that case, yes, it's different because it's an object name rather than a file name.  This means that file name restrictions specific to NTFS don't apply, and neither do those introduced by the Win32 subsystem; essentially, you're talking directly to the kernel, so only the kernel's rules matter.

Comment: @Harry Aside: File name restrictions are specific to the Windows API. NTFS does not restrict file names with the only exception being the NUL character ([Source: Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Internals)).

Comment: @IInspectable: that particular assertion in the Wikipedia article lacks a reference, so I'm not entirely certain that it is true.  If I get a chance I'll try it out. :-)  IIRC, the NTFS drivers do report a length limit of 255 characters for file names, though it's possible they don't enforce it.

Comment: @Harry I was referring to restrictions with respect to legal characters, which do no exist with the exception of a NUL character. File names are limited to 255 UTF-16 code points (also stated in the Wikipedia article).

Comment: @IInspectable: I've done some testing using NtSetInformationFile, and had a peek at the Windows Research Kernel source, and it looks as though the NTFS drivers are in fact enforcing at least some of the illegal character restrictions.  I've edited the Wikipedia article to clarify what I believe to be the intended meaning of the relevant paragraph.